# Swagger fails to load 2 HttpGet methods in a controller of an asp.net core web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a controller that needs to have 2 actions. One to load an entity by id and one to load all entities. I wanted to have the first action take the id from query, so I wrote these two methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<cfEntity> GetById([FromQuery]Guid id)
{
    return await repository.GetAsync(id);
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<cfEntity>> Get()
{
    return await repository.GetAsync();
}
```

When I run the app, swagger fails to load the api definition because there are 2 HttpGet methods on the same route.

One way I managed to make it work is by declaring the first method like this

```
[Route("{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<cfEntity> GetById(Guid id)
{
    return await repository.GetAsync(id);
}
```

But then the id must be part of the route and can no longer be passed in the query.

Another way is by having only one method with the id optional and do different things depending on if it's null or not. But I absolutely don't like this.

Is there any other approach to be able to have query parameters? I dont want the 2 methods to have different routes, like for example api/entity/all because they concern the same resource.

Comment: "_I dont want the 2 methods to have different routes, like for example api/entity/all because they concern the same resource._". Those two methods don't concern the same resource though, one returns a single resource based on an `ID` and the other returns all resources. Please explain in more detail and clarity what it is you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Peppermintology in my understanding of REST best practices, an entity of persons for example should be accessed by endpoint /Person. Then either via route /id or query parameter ?id= you could access specific person. I am asking if it's possible to make the later to work with swagger.

Comment: By convention, a *collection* (more than one) of `Person` would be accessed at `/persons` and a single `Person` at `/persons/{id}`. Your `[Route("{id}"]` is correct, you want to add `[FromRoute]` before `Guid` in your `GetById` method.

Comment: "Then either via route /id or query parameter ?id= you could access specific person. I am asking if it's possible to make the later to work with swagger." " I dont want the 2 methods to have different routes," Do you mean you want the 2 Get methods to have the same route? Maybe that's not possible.  Via route /id is the easiest way .